# Retrieve Variable from Batch Task and Use It in launch.json in VS Code

Tags: windows, batch-file, visual-studio-code

I have a batch file which sets a variable using the following:

```
set "MyVariable=Test"
```

I have configured a task in tasks.json to run this batch file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "VariableTest",
        "command": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/VariableTest.bat",
        "args": [],
        "type": "shell"
    }]
}
```

How can I retrieve the value of this variable from my launch.json file? "VariableTest" is setup as a preLaunchTask for the launch configurations, and parameters in this configuration depend on this variable.

I am of course running Windows (10).

Thanks!

Comment: You could create another batch file from your first batchfile and then execute that batch file in another dependant task using the `"dependsOn": ["firstTask"]` option

Answer (score 3):

This variable is set in a separate shell.

You need to store the value in a file and use an extension to retrieve the content.

Use

```
echo SomeText > c:\temp\VariableResult.txt
```

to store the variable value in a file.

You can use [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) and the command `extension.commandvariable.file.content`

An example `launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File Args",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args" : ["${input:variableResult}"],
      "preLaunchTask": "VariableTest"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "variableResult",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
      "args": {
        "fileName": "c:\\temp\\VariableResult.txt"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

If the output file contains key-value pairs you can [specify the key to use](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content-key-value-pairs).